# Compose TextField Clear Focus onTap outside textfield

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I used to use this function to lose focus on my editText

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
                v.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

but in jetpack compose I have not found the way to do this, usually for this behavior to my parent composable at the time of tapping I do a clearFocus but that does not convince me, do you know if there is a way to do it as before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my code which I handle it myself in compose itself and it does not relate to activity .

You need to call this func.

```
 val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
 val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
```

And set parent to be clickable to hide keyboard and clearFocus

Here is the final code.

```
var isBold by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val textState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
StackoverflowTheme {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(
                indication = null,
                interactionSource = remember {
                    MutableInteractionSource()
                } // disable ripple effect
            ) { // call this func for clear
                keyboardController?.hide()
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            },
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            TextField(
                value = textState.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    textState.value = it
                },
                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    lineHeight = 24.sp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontWeight = if (isBold) FontWeight.Bold else FontWeight.Normal
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done)
            )
            Button(onClick = {
                isBold = !isBold
            }) {
                Text(text = "Toggle Bold")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you dont want to use the clickable, You can try with this.

```
Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit){
                detectTapGestures {
                    keyboardController?.hide()
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                }
            },
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    )
```

Comment: Note: I am using Material3